# Mix of normal and darken tikz blend mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, blend-mode

I am trying to figure out how to highlight some part of the source code in the `lstlisting` environment in a Beamer presentation without affecting the syntax highlighting and spacing. The background color for `lstlisting` is very light gray and the highlighted code should be marked by a light orange color box.

My current solution is based on a tikz rectangle with the `overlay` option drawn around the remembered nodes with the `darken` blend mode to make the source code visible. Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\colorlet{myorange}{orange!50}

\newcommand\bh{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node(begin highlight){};}

\newcommand\eh[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node (end highlight) {};%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]%
    \draw[draw=none,fill=myorange,blend mode=#1]%
      ($(begin highlight)+(-0.1,-0.3)$) rectangle ($(end highlight)+(0.1,0.4)$);}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray!30},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  escapechar=@]
int main()
{
  @\bh@int i = 0;@\eh{darken}@ @\bh@int i = 0;@\eh{normal}@
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

This solution works such that the black source code is visible, but the problem is that the highlight color (`myorange`) gets mixed with the background color (`lightgray!30`) (*left example*). And, I would like to have the "non-mixed" `myorange` color there instead (*right example but with visible text*).

Is there any blending mode, or any other way, that would work such as follows?

1. When the background color is darker than the foreground, the background is used.
2. When the background color is lighter that the foreground, the foreground is used.

Comment: Off topic: you don't need to load `xcolor`. Beamer already loads it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw the rectangle before the source code with the help of tikzmark (you need to compile twice):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\colorlet{myorange}{orange!50}
\newcounter{mynode}
\newcommand\bh{%
  \stepcounter{mynode}%
  \tikzmark{begin highlight \themynode}%
  \iftikzmark{begin highlight \themynode}
   {%
     \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
     \draw[draw=none,fill=myorange]%
      ($(pic cs:begin highlight \themynode)+(-0.1,-0.3)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:end highlight \themynode)+(0.1,0.4)$);
   }{}}

\newcommand\eh{%
    \tikzmark{end highlight \themynode}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray!30},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  escapechar=@]
int main()
{
  @\bh@int i = 0;@\eh@ @\bh@int i = 0;@\eh@
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thansk!